# How do I count the number of unique values in a csv using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, iteration

Maybe someone can post another question that already has an answer to my question, but I have been unable to find it.

My dataset is a 10,000+ row csv that looks like this:

```
    col_1          col_2
   a, b, c, d       9 
   a, b, c          3
   b, d             5
   a, c, e          1
```

I am wondering how do I iterate through col_1 to pull out each letter and then sum the amount of col_2 if it shows up.

So for this example, the output would be:

```
a - 13
b - 17
c - 13
d - 14
e - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the dummies, multiply then sum:

```
df['col_1'].str.get_dummies(",").mul(df['col_2'],axis=0).sum()
```

---

```
a    13
b    17
c    13
d    14
e     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  Upvoted.  See whether `get_dummies()` should be passed `', '` with one more space as well ?

Comment: @SeaBean Thank you :) , thats a valuable suggestion for one who has spaces after the commas. I assumed that the question is typed out and hence have had additional spaces but however the general idea remains same.

Answer (score 1):

Try `split` with `explode` then `groupby`

```
df.assign(col_1 = df['col_1'].str.split(', ')).explode('col_1').groupby('col_1')['col_2'].sum()
Out[172]: 
col_1
a    13
b    17
c    13
d    14
e     1
Name: col_2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

As per what you are showinig in the question, I assume that you already have the data in `df`

`Split` the string on comma and `explode` the list and finally call `value_counts`

```py
df['col1'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
```

**SAMPLE RUN**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a,b,c',  'a,b', 'b,c']})
df['col1'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
Out[82]: 
b    3
c    2
a    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = (
    df.assign(
        col_1=df["col_1"].apply(lambda x: list(map(str.strip, x.split(","))))
    )
    .explode("col_1")
    .groupby("col_1")
    .sum()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       col_2
col_1       
a         13
b         17
c         13
d         14
e          1
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me. Thanks!